# Jumping to specific \onslide

Tags: hyperlink

I am making a presentation in Beamer using `\onslide` and using `\hyperlink` I can easily jump to the first `\onslide` environment on a different frame.

However, I would like to be able to jump to a specific `\onslide` environment on a different frame.

If the frame I would like to jump to looked like this

```
\begin{frame}

\onslide<1->{x}

\onslide<2->{y}

\onslide<3->{z}

\end{frame}
```

is there some way to jump to this frame, that will immediately show the content of the two first `\onslide` environments, but not the last one?

I have tried placing a hyperlink within an `\onslide` environment, but this hyperlink seems to apply to the entire frame.

Comment: always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hypertarget` is overlay-aware, so you can use `\hypertarget<num>{<target>}{<stuff>}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First frame}
  
  Jump to next frame: Slide \hyperlink{xxx}{1}, \hyperlink{yyy}{2}, \hyperlink{zzz}{3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second frame}
  \onslide<1->{\hypertarget<1>{xxx}{}x}
  \onslide<2->{\hypertarget<2>{yyy}{}y}
  \onslide<3->{\hypertarget<3>{zzz}{}z}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Above I set a *blank* target just to ensure the content isn't copied across the remainder of the slides within the same frame.

Comment: I have now implemented your suggestion, and it does exactly what I need. Thanks for your help.